# display file content from the beginning up to a multi-line pattern

Tags: text-processing

How can I display file content from the beginning up to some multi-line pattern **without including the pattern itself?**

For example, if I had a text file like this:

```
cat
dog
fox
cow
dove
bird
bunny
gnu
hen
dove
bird
buffalo
```

and if my pattern was this:

```
dove
bird
bunny
```

what I'd like to get would be:

```
cat
dog
fox
cow
```

My real file is huge so if there are multiple ways to achieve this, I'd prefer faster ways.

**Also, I asked a similar question related to this just now, but it's different so please don't mark this as duplicate just because of that!**

Comment: If the pattern is not found anywhere within the file should it print everything, or nothing?

Comment: @steeldriver, hopefully I'd like it to give an error instead in that kind of situation, but my file basically always has the pattern so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: `sed -n '1N;N;/dove\nbird\bunny/q;P;D'` will hold 3 lines in the pattern space at any point in time. Then we print the leftmost, slide it out, append next... till we hit the multi-line pat, at which point we promptly quit. Since the pattern is sure to be found, hence no need for storage.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the input line-wise with `sed` and chain the multi-line pattern match:

```sed
/pat1/ { N; N; ...; /pat2\npat3\n.../q }
```

So in your example, that would be e.g.:

```
sed -n '/^dove$/ { N; N; /\nbird\nbunny$/q; }; p' infile
```

Output:

```
cat
dog
fox
cow
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate `sed` approach, that uses branching to maintain a 3-line buffer in pattern space and test it against the multiline pattern, quitting when found:

```
sed -n '
  :a
  $q
  N
  /dove\nbird\nbunny/q
  3,$ {
    P
    D
  }
  ba
' file
```

With GNU sed, you can use the `Q` command to quit without printing the current pattern space, plus it allows a more free-form syntax e.g.

```
sed -e :a -e '$Q' -e 'N;/dove\nbird\nbunny/Q' -e '3,${P;D}' -e 'ba' file
```

or

```
sed ':a; $Q; N; /dove\nbird\nbunny/Q; 3,${P;D}; ba' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of a Python hack to do that.

#### Code:

```
# !/usr/bin/python
import sys
with open(sys.argv[2], 'rU') as f:
    patterns = f.readlines()

result = None
with open(sys.argv[3], 'rU') as f:
    last_match = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if line != patterns[last_match]:
            last_match = 0
        else:
            last_match += 1
            if last_match == len(patterns):
                result = i + 1 - len(patterns)
                break

if result != None:
    if sys.argv[1] == 'tail':
        print("tail -n+%d %s" % (result+1, sys.argv[3]))
    else:
        print("head -n%d %s" % (result, sys.argv[3]))
```

#### Run it

To output up to the pattern:

```
`python split_on_pattern.py head pattern_file data_file`
```

To output from the pattern on:

```
`python split_on_pattern.py tail pattern_file data_file`
```