# display file content from some muti-line pattern to the end

Tags: text-processing

How can I display file content from some multi-line pattern to the end **including the pattern itself**?

**I asked a similar question just now but it's different and I thought I should post this as a separate, new question. So please don't mark this duplicate simply because of that!**

For example, if I had a text file like this:

```
cat
dog
fox
cow
dove
bird
bunny
gnu
hen
dove
bird
buffalo
```

and if my pattern was this:

```
dove
bird
bunny
```

what I'd like to get would be:

```
dove
bird
bunny
gnu
hen
dove
bird
buffalo
```

My real file is huge so if there are multiple ways to achieve this, I'd prefer faster ways.

Comment: What if the pattern appears multiple times in the file?

Comment: @Thor, in my particular situation, the pattern can't appear multiple times so it doesn't matter.

Comment: `sed -e '1N;N;/dove\nbird\nbunny/!D' -e ':a' -e 'n;ba'` will hold 3 lines at any time in the pattern space till the time the golden lines are found. At which point we setup a loop and keep spitting the pattern space till we hit the eof.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print from the first time the pattern appears, it is easy. Follow the same logic I described in [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372560/17666), but with some extra logic:

*parse.sed*

```sed
/^dove$/ {            # Match multi-line pattern
  N                   #  /
  N                   # /
  /\nbird\nbunny$/bb  # When matched jump to label b
}
d                     # Restart with next line if no match
:b                    # \
n                     #  Print the rest of the file
bb                    # /
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -f parse.sed infile
```

Or as a portable one-liner:

```
sed -n -e '/^dove$/{N;N;/\nbird\nbunny$/bb' -e '};d;:b' -e 'p;n;bb' infile
```

The output in both cases:

```
dove
bird
bunny
gnu
hen
dove
bird
buffalo
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl solution:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print $1,$2 if m/(dove.bird.bunny)(.*)/sm' myfile
```

This outputs:

```
dove
bird
bunny
gnu
hen
dove
bird
buffalo
```

The `-0777` switch turns on *slurp* mode which reads the whole file into memory.  the use of `sm` modifiers to the match allows a dot to match a newline while treating the string as multiple lines.

The `-n` switch creates a read loop for the input file. When the sequence *dove.bind.bunny* is seen, it's captured in `$1` with the remaining lines in `$2` and this is what's printed if the overall match succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -v RS=" " '{                        # considering space as record separator
                  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {  # iterating through all fields
                     if ($i=="dove" && $(i+1)=="bird" && $(i+2)=="bunny") { f=1 } 
                     if (f) print $i 
                  } 
               }' file
```

The output:

```
dove
bird
bunny
gnu
hen
dove
bird
buffalo
```